# "textual UML" tool with XMI generation for domain modeling

Tags: uml

I used to design my model with PlantUML.

```
@startuml
class Dummy {
  {static} String id
  {abstract} void methods()
}
@enduml
```

[image: Dummy class diagram's generated image]

I like to have the "textual UML" which is easy to version with a git repository.
But unfortunatly XMI is not supported for the moment.

My company is using MagicDraw and wants to stick with it although it is hard to maintain between versions because it is not "textual".

Thank you for suggesting suitable software.